# Object stored in list of interface, what happens to non interface event registration

Tags: c#, list, events, interface, eventhandler

Assume the following (pseudo) C# code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<bool> ConnectedStateChanged;
}

public interface IIncomingFoo : IFoo
{
    public event EventHandler<string> MessageReceived;
}

public Foo : IIncomingFoo 
{
    //implementation
}

//other class:
public List<IFoo> FooObjectsList = new List<IFoo>();

var myObject = new Foo();
myObject.Name = "FooObect in list";
myObject.ConnectedStateChanged += ConnectedStateChangedHandler;
myObject.MessageReceived += MessageReceivedHandler;

FooObjectsList.Add(myObject);
```

Now the thing is that when firing the ConnectedStateChanged event from the Foo object, the handler is called and I'm able to handle the event.
The (from my point of view) weird thing is that when I'm firing the MessageReceived event from the Foo class, the handler is not called. Despite the fact that when looking at event.GetInvocationList(), the handling function is listed.

Any idea whats happening here? It looks like the registrations which are not on the (in this case) IFoo interface are 'foregotten'?

Comment: How are the events being fired? Are you sure the MessageReceived is being fired?

Comment: To answer this properly you really need to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - in theory the event should be firing fine.